# Auto prediction/dictionary/suggestion support on android EditText

Tags: android

Android Messaging EditText supports the auto suggestion, i want to provide same type of suggestion or dictionary support to custom Edit text.

I have already added intput type with Auto correct and auto complete

`android:inputType="textAutoCorrect|textAutoComplete"`

but it's not working, I verified implementation on Android 2.3 & 4.0.3
Is there any proper way for providing auto suggestion or dictionary support to EditText ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the line `android:inputType="textAutoCorrect|textAutoComplete"` , and do not call `setInputType` in code.